# Vaadin - data from multiple objects to Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

I want to insert data from multiple objects (eg. from 2 Spring Data entities); I know how to make left join from multiple entities, but I'm not sure how to make Custom object from that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vaadin [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) is typed using [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). For example: `Grid<Person>`. You cannot have multiple types here.

If you need to join data from multiple objects, you must create a middle layer to produce [DTO (Data Transfer Object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). The DTO collects properties from multiple source objects. This is a common practice in more complex business application, not limited to Vaadin.

Comment: By the way, the new [*Records* (JEP 359)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) feature being previewed in Java 14 may help with this kind of work.